# Wordpress Content Type in Category.php

Tags: wordpress, content-type, taxonomy

Very simple setup, I'm using 1 template for multiple taxonomies. So example:

I have basic category + customtypetaxonomy. Both of them have terms. I'm displaying the posts of these terms in the same template - category.php. Which works great and how I want it.

However, I want to make small changes in this template based on the taxonomie it is getting its posts from. But I cannot figure out what function I need to use to get this.

For example: single_cat_title() gives me the title of the term (category)

But what I need is either the slug or the ID. Is there a way to do this? Something like single_cat_id or single_cat_slug. I have tried $cat but it doesn't give me any output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use WP_Query. Like this:

```
    $ThisQuery = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name'  => 'MyCategory',
                                      'meta_key'       => 'MyCustomFieldValue',
                                      'posts_per_page' => 10 ) ); // Number of posts

    if ( $ThisQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $ThisQuery->have_posts() ) : $ThisQuery->the_post();
...

    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Modify the array to include the elements that identify the posts you want to fetch

Another EXAMPLE:

```
<?php
$Args = array( //Category
  'cat'           => 5,  // Category id.
  'category_name' => 'MyCategory',  // Category Name.
  //Taxonomy
  'tax_query'     => array( 'relation' => 'AND', // Could be OR
                            array( 'taxonomy' => 'MyTaxonomy1',
                                   'field'    => 'MySlug1',
                                   'terms'    => array( 'MyTerm11',
                                                        'MyTerm12' ), ),
                            array( 'taxonomy' => 'MyTaxonomy2',
                                   'field'    => 'MySlug2',
                                   'terms'    => array( 'MyTerm21',
                                                        'MyTerm22',
                                                        'MyTerm23' ), ) ), );
$ThisQuery = new WP_Query( $Args );
if ( $ThisQuery->have_posts() ) : while ( $ThisQuery->have_posts() ) : $ThisQuery->the_post();
  // Do Stuff
endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for the answer. But this is not the answer to my problem. I already have the posts I want. category.php makes sure of that. Problem is that when I'm calling category.php by going to the permalink of the taxonomie and term. I cannot retrieve the taxonomie. So example:

mypage.com/taxonomie/term/

When on the term page, I want to be able to retrieve 'taxonomie'.

Comment: @Redox: WP_Query allows to retrieve all information. I updated the answer with another example.